# Ubuntu 14.04.2 and 15.04 compiz error after reboot stuck in a login loop, but 14.04 works

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, compiz, 15.04

I'm having a problem after installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 and 15.04, after I install and reboot I cant login, I checked .Xauthority and everything was fine I also tried some other methods of repairing it found here but nothing worked. I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 and it works even after I did `sudo apt-get upgrade`and`dist-upgrade`. I don't know what could be the problem bt Kubuntu 15.04 also works.
Thanks